# create (represented) a line $(∆)$ such that ($P$ point from space )

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $\angle CAD $ and $\angle EFB$ be two angle such that :
$(AC)//(BE)$ , $(AD)//(BF)$

create (represented) a line $(∆)$ such that  ($P$ point from space ) :

$$\begin{cases}P\in (\Delta)\\(\Delta\cap(AC)=X\\(\Delta)\cap(AD)=Y\\(\Delta)\cap(BE)=Z\\(∆)\cap(BF)=T\\XY=ZT\end{cases}$$
[image]

I don't know the trick to create

Can you give a Hints!

---

Thanks!